# Plot points based on values of a factor column

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like the one below. This is just the first 9 row of 54 rows. Each Stream name is repeated 18 times, 3 stream names (18*3=54)

```
stream     n     1         2         3       means
1   Brooks 3 0.42707006 1.9353659 1.4333884 1.8566225
2  Siouxon 3 0.90503736 0.2838483 0.2838483 1.0023212
3 Speelyai 3 0.08554021 0.7359903 0.4841935 0.7359903
4   Brooks 4 1.43338843 1.8566225 0.0000000 1.3242210
5  Siouxon 4 0.50574543 0.5057454 0.2838483 0.4756304
6 Speelyai 4 0.32252396 0.4343109 0.6653132 2.2294652
7   Brooks 5 0.88984211 1.8566225 0.7741612 1.3242210
8  Siouxon 5 0.47501800 0.7383634 0.5482181 0.6430847
9 Speelyai 5 0.15079491 0.2615963 0.4738504 0.0000000
```

I have also created a `vector` of values. There are 18 different values. Each stream (3 total) has a mean related to a value in this vector. For example, the first three rows in the data frame, relate to the first value in vector (3). The next three rows (4:6) relate to the second value in the vector (7.5). In hindsight, I should have replaced the `n` column in my dataframe with the values found in the rates vector. That might have made more sense.

```
rates <- c(3,7.5,10,13,15,17,19.5,22,25.5,28,30.5,32,33.5,36,40.5,44,46,48.5)
```

I am trying to create a plot with `rates` on the x axis and the means from my dataframe on the y-axis. However, I would like to create a plot for each level of a factor, in this case "stream" is a 3 level factor found in the dataframe

```
Levels: Brooks Siouxon Speelyai
```

So, to recap, I would like to take the "means" column values for any ONE stream and plot them on the Yaxis with `rates` vector on the x. So I should have one plot for "Brooks" that will have 18 points (18 means~18 rates found in the rates vector).

Well I have now changed the data frame so I can do away with the rates vector. Here is the new data frame.

```
    stream n  rates     means          1         2
1   Brooks 3   3.0     0.9629152 0.42707006 1.9353659
2  Siouxon 3   3.0     0.5831929 0.90503736 0.2838483
3 Speelyai 3   3.0     0.6199235 0.08554021 0.7359903
4   Brooks 4   7.5     0.9722707 1.43338843 1.8566225
5  Siouxon 4   7.5     0.5865031 0.50574543 0.5057454
6 Speelyai 4   7.5     0.6118634 0.32252396 0.4343109
7   Brooks 5  10.0     0.9637475 0.88984211 1.8566225
8  Siouxon 5  10.0     0.5804420 0.47501800 0.7383634
9 Speelyai 5  10.0     0.5959238 0.15079491 0.2615963
```

I hope this is much more clear, and cleaner. I would still like the same result, that is, a plot for each stream name (so three plots) that have values in the mean column on Y-axis, and values in the rates column on X-axis

Comment: It isn't obvious to me why your data frame has 9 rows, but your rates vectors has 18 elements.  How will these play together?

Comment: Supposing you want the `rates` as breaks on the x-axis, you are trying to make a strange plot: All the mean values will be plotted close to the y-axis. Maybe you can show us what you have already tried or else explain better what you want. As the question is now stated, it is quite unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the post with more information right now.

Comment: Made the edits, hopefully this is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for facets in ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(your_data, aes(x = rates, y = means)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ stream)
```

To generate a plot with just one stream, subset your data

```
ggplot(your_data[your_data$stream == "Brooks", ],
       aes(x = rates, y = means)) +
  geom_point()
```

To do all of the streams individually, something like this:

```
individual_stream_data = split(your_data, your_data$stream)
individual_stream_plots = lapply(individual_stream_data,
    function(x) {
        ggplot(x, aes(x = rates, y = means)) +
          geom_point() +
          labs(title = x$stream[1])
})
```

This will generate a list of plots, so you can print them or save them one-at-a-time:

```
 print(individual_stream_plots[[1]])
 print(individual_stream_plots[[3]]) # etc.
```

Comment: YES!, I was close, but did not have the facet_wrap part. Thanks. So, how can I just get 1 stream per plot, so no facet. Also, is it possible to specify a value to have a horizontal line at?